# Introducing here sdk3.14, and the build project fails when minifyEnable is turned on

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, proguard

When introducing here sdk3.14, and the build project fails when minifyEnable is turned on.
it is log

```
Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
  Class       = [com/here/odnp/cell/PlatformCellManagerApi29]
  Method      = [requestCellUpate(Z)V]
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common super class of [com/here/odnp/cell/PlatformCellManagerApi29$ImplicitCellInfoListener] (with 1 known super classes) and [com/here/odnp/cell/PlatformCellManagerApi29$ExplicitCellInfoListener] (with 1 known super classes))
Unexpected error while preverifying:
  Class       = [com/here/odnp/cell/PlatformCellManagerApi29]
  Method      = [requestCellUpate(Z)V]
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common super class of [com/here/odnp/cell/PlatformCellManagerApi29$ImplicitCellInfoListener] (with 1 known super classes) and [com/here/odnp/cell/PlatformCellManagerApi29$ExplicitCellInfoListener] (with 1 known super classes))
Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find common super class of [com/here/odnp/cell/PlatformCellManagerApi29$ImplicitCellInfoListener] (with 1 known super classes) and [com/here/odnp/cell/PlatformCellManagerApi29$ExplicitCellInfoListener] (with 1 known super classes)
```

and my build.gradle config:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion(27)
    buildToolsVersion("27.0.3")
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.sfic.extmse.operator"
        minSdkVersion(19)
        targetSdkVersion(22)
        multiDexEnabled = true
        versionCode = property("APP_VERSION_CODE").toString().toInt()
        versionName = property("APP_VERSION_NAME").toString()
        ndk {
            abiFilters("armeabi", "x86", "armeabi-v7a")
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        create("preRelease") {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = false
            isDebuggable = false
            isJniDebuggable = false
            isRenderscriptDebuggable = false
            matchingFallbacks = listOf("release")
            proguardFile(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"))
            proguardFile(file("proguard-rules.pro"))
        }
    }
}
```

i try to use proguard to fix it:

```
# HERE
-dontwarn com.here.**
-keep  class com.here.**{*;}
-dontoptimize
-dontshrink
```

but it is unuseful.

the project use android.support not androidx . i try to just change complieSdkVersion 27 to 29, it success, but i cannot change support to androidx, because my dependiences use support

Comment: You can still migrate to AndroidX even if your dependencies haven't migrated yet as explained on the [migration guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) - Jetifier rewrites your dependencies as if they were using AndroidX.

Comment: But this project use Fragmentation,The implementation of FragmentManager is different in AndroidX and support, so we cannot temporarily migrate to AndroidX.

Comment: Yes you can. You'd always use the AndroidX version in your code

Comment: I tried using the [reverse](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jetifier#reverse_mode) mode of jetifier to no avail.